# Problems running Gradle project

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, wrapper

I am new to Stack Overflow and asking questions. So, I was wondering how can I fix the problem

```
Execution failed for task ':client-app:yarn_install'. > A problem occurred starting process 'command 'yarn.cmd''.
```

I am currently trying to run a Gradle project from its wrapper file but having this error.

I have tried running `".\gradlew.bat bootRun"` which gives me this problem

Comment: The error message is not complete. Please attach the entire output after performing gradlew.bat bootRun. Does it work from the command line outside of IntelliJ IDEA?